# If $a + b + c = 50$, maximum value of $ab^2c$

Tags: functions

If $a + b + c = 50$ and $a, b, c$ are nonnegative even integers, then find the greatest value of $ab^2c$.

Maximum value occurs when $a=b=c$ but not able to approach it as $a,b,c$ are non-negative even number.

Comment: No, that's not the maximum value. That would've been the case if we were asking about $abc$. Consider, for instance, $15\cdot 20^2\cdot 15>(50/3)^4$.

Comment: The question ask about $ab^2c$

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi I know. That is what I pointed out. If the question had been about $abc$, then $a = b = c$ would have been the maximum. But the question is not about $abc$, and therefore $a = b = c$ is not the maximum, as for instance $a = c = 15, b = 20$ makes $ab^2c$ larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  $a, b, c$ are non-negative even integers then $ab^2c$ must be a multiple of $2^4=16$

Even if you removed the even integer requirement, you could not exceed $4\left(\frac{50}{4}\right)^4 = 97656.25$, which rounded down to a multiple of $16$ would be $97344$.  That is an acceptable answer as $97344 =12\times 26^2 \times 12$ and $12+26+12=50$ and so is largest

Considering the possible answers:

- $97344$ is correct
- $97656$ is not a multiple of $16$
- $94864 = 14\times 22^2 \times 14$ and $14+22+14=50$ so is acceptable but is smaller than $97344$
- $94972$ is not a multiple of $16$ and is smaller than $97344$

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM we have

$$a+\frac12 b+\frac12b+c \ge 4\sqrt[4]{\frac{ab^2c}4}$$

Comment: The four choice are (1) 97344 (2) 97656 (3) 94864 (4) 94972 out of which one is correct

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi You have an application of AM-GM right here. You know the value of the left-hand side, and you know how to make the two sides of AM-GM equal, right? Then just apply that knowledge to what this answer has given you.

Comment: I get $97656.25 \ge ab^2c$ hence I presume answer is 97656

Comment: One of the choice is (1) 97344 (2*) 97656 (3) 94864 (4) 94972 out of which one is correct

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi It should be $ab^2c \le 4\left(\frac{50}4\right)^4$.

Comment: You'll have to apply a little thought yourself now, both @user and Arthur have helped you out immensely on this question.

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi The maximum by AM-GM is attained for $a=\frac b 2=c=\frac{50}4=12.5$ but since $a,b,c$ are integer we need to check $12*12*26^2$ or $12*13*25^2$ and so on, you ca easily guess which is the maximum.